# Is there a way to get a Bit field in SQL (non transact)

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, binary-data

Let's say the field comes with a number like `134479872`, I'd like it to revert back to `0xffffffff` and extract each pair like `Oxff00000`, `0x00ff0000`, `0x0000ff00` and `0x000000ff` in a separate field. The bits are supposed to tell me info about a left, right, top and bottom edge: First two bits are for the left edge, two next ones for the right and so on.

Now I tried `SELECT CAST(myfield as Binary(8))` to get the `0xffffffff` format but it does not accept it. From there I could work with `Mid()` to get the two fields I need, that last part I am ok with it.

Note that my SQL is dealt with Access 2010, and it does not accept Transact-SQL functions.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I guess that you need to start again and store you values in a format that Access can give you the return that you want. It would seem simpler to have 4 different columns of integer for the 4 values, this would take relatively little place in memory and result in faster querying because there would be no data processing.

Comment: The data provided comes from another software, I don't have power on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `Hex$()` function.

```
? Hex$(134479872)
8040000
```

To pad it to 8 characters:

```
? Right("00000000" & Hex$(134479872), 8)
08040000
```

But if you utilize the full 32 bits, you will run into problems - VBA Longints are signed.

```
? &H7FFFFFFF
 2147483647 

? Hex$(2147483648)
<Overflow error>
```

Comment: Seems Right("00000000" & Hex$(134479872), 8) Is what I need. Thanks

Comment: Good. :) -- Note for clarification and future questions: 0xff is not a Bit, it is a Byte. @VBSMartin